# How can I open a console command for the erlang application of RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I would like to start the rabbitmqserver with the virtual machine and no the scripts something likke rabbitmq-server console, is there any such command or way to start the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

`export RABBITMQ_ALLOW_INPUT=true
./sbin/rabbitmq-server`